# Can you change a ruby on rails form's remote status on the fly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form that I use as a remote form in one page and would like to reuse the form for another page and not have it be remote.  What would be the easiest way to make it remote in one situation and not remote in the other?  In the case that I don't want the form to be remote, the form is the only thing displayed for a particular url.  In the other case, the form is used embedded in a more complicated structure and I have the remote functionality working there.  I just need the submit button to request an html response and not a javascript response.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two methods:

#### 1: Use jQuery to disable the remote methods

You can use jQuery to "disable" a remote form. It's a two command process and you need to do it in order:

```
$('form#form_id').removeAttr('data-remote');
$('form#form_id').remoteData('remote');
```

#### 2: Use Rails partials & variables

Create a partial (if one doesn't exist already) for your form. The form helper will look something like this

```
form_for @object, remote: remote
```

Then, call the partial using `<%= render partial: 'form', locals: { remote: true } %>` or `<%= render partial: 'form', locals: { remote: false } %>`

Comment: Thank you very much!  I contemplated using the jQuery approach, but since I was already using partials and the form_for helper, I chose your second suggestion.  Because I'm using the same form for two different actions, I had to pass the local through two layers of partials rather than just one, is this bad practice according to anyone's opinion?

Answer (score 1):

You extract your form to a partial, a new file starting with underscore, for example _my_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @resource, url: url, remote: remote do %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

And you use it in your two files: like this:

## To make it remote with url1:

```
<%= render partial: 'my_form', locals: { url: 'url1', remote: true } %>
```

## To make it non remote with url2:

```
<%= render partial: 'my_form', locals: { url: 'url2', remote: false } %>
```

Note `'my_form'` will be according in which folder you save partial. if you save in `shared` folder for example, you will use `'shared/my_form'`

Comment: Thanks very much!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Since I use the same form for two separate actions, is it bad practice to pass in a local through more than one layer of partials in your opinion?